# Is there a way to make a firebase auth token for development?

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-authentication

## Background

I am building a react native app that posts data to a node server that then posts data to a firebase via the admin firebase library.

To post data I am bypassing the app entirely and using [postman](https://www.getpostman.com/docs/) for speed.

## Problem

My routes are now using an authentication header that should contain a firebase auth token. To get this token I need to sign in as a user in my app and log the token and copy it out to use in postman. This takes time and the token is only valid for 1 hour.

## Question

Is there a way to put firebase into "dev mode" and use a persistent token in my Authorization header or perhaps some other technique to speed up the process?

Comment: If you're using Firebase Admin you're able to create a custom token: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/create-custom-tokens
And to check the token provided: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens

Comment: @t3__rry I'm aware of this, I have already created the token on a different route. I need to use an existing or refresh token on a new route to send in an Auth header

Comment: Has there been any news since? I am having a similiar issue as well

Answer (score 0):

I got my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72766800/16306754) thanks to [user680141](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8035620/user680141).

You need to create a sample user on firebase, then use the [Firebase Auth REST API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/auth#section-sign-in-email-password).

You can then get the token directly from POSTMAN using

```
https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/accounts:signInWithPassword
```

with these items in the body:

```
{
    key: "YOUR_API_KEY"  <= you need to put your firebase api key here
    email: "your@email.com",
    password: "your-password",
    returnSecureToken: true
}
```

There is currently no way to get a persistent token for development,  but this should speed up the process.

Comment: In case it helps anyone else this one seems more up to date:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/58935761/5117487 (note api version diff). 

Also I kept getting a 401 and it was because in postman I had a bearer token being passed that I had to wipe from the auth tab. When that was gone it started working.