# Simple way to get a firebase auth token (development)

Tags: node.js, firebase, api, firebase-authentication, jwt

**Background**

I am using laravel to create some backend APIs.

These APIs require to be authenticated using firebase auth.

I created a firebase authentication function in my project, and now need the JWT token to test it out using postman.

I am not in charge of the front end, so I do not need to create a login system, and if possible I would like to have a token I can permanently use while developing.

**Question**

Is there any way I can easily get a permanent firebase token for development, without having to create a client side log in system?

**Similar Question**

[Is there a way to make a firebase auth token for development?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48339854/is-there-a-way-to-make-a-firebase-auth-token-for-development)

I found this similar question from three years ago but it was unanswered.

Any help would be appreciated!

**Alternative Question**

What is the easiest way to issue a Firebase API token step-by-step?
I am a bit new and couldn't understand the contents of this page that well.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/create-custom-tokens

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using Postman, why not:

1. Create a user via the Firebase Auth web console
2. Create a request in Postman that logs in via the [Firebase Auth REST API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/auth#section-sign-in-email-password)?

Something like POST to  `https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/accounts:signInWithPassword?key=[API_KEY]` with body:

```
{
    "email": "abc@def.com",
    "password":"password",
    "returnSecureToken":true
}
```